# Text in a webkit scrollbar

Tags: css

You can stylize scrollbars:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

You can use css to add content:

https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Can you put text in that scrollbar? Like letters stacked on top of each other, like the title on a book's spine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible using native scrollbars, as they are not proper `HTML` elements and browsers take turns at not allowing them to be styled in the name of *usability* and *accessibility*. But totally possible using a scrollbar plugin.
My personal favorite (for a number of reasons): [`simplebar`](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar).

```js
window.SimpleBar = new SimpleBar(document.querySelector('[data-scrollbar]'),{ autoHide: false });
window.onresize = function() {
  window.SimpleBar.recalculate();
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;margin:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body>[data-scrollbar] {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

body>[data-scrollbar] .spacer {
  height: 200vh;
}

body>[data-scrollbar] .simplebar-track.vertical::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'scrollbar';
  width: 1px;
  word-break: break-all;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index:3
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@2.0.3/umd/simplebar.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@2.0.3/umd/simplebar.js"></script>

<body>
  <div data-scrollbar>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I chose a clumsy `::before` element to display the text. You can go ahead and prepend a proper `html` structure, wrapping each letter in a `span` and distributing/centering them using `flexbox`.

---

If you would rather apply the text to the scrollbar pill rather than the track, you have to replace this line

```
body>[data-scrollbar] .simplebar-track.vertical::before {
```

with

```
body>[data-scrollbar] .simplebar-track.vertical .simplebar-scrollbar::before {
```

in the script above. Use plugin docs and `CSS` to customize its appearance.

Comment: Thank you. In this case I'm using a widget that comes with it's own scrollbar in an iframe. I can apply custom css, but that's it.